# In a spreadsheet, can you force pasting from the system clipboard?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, copy-paste, libreoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets

I've noticed what seems to be new behavior the past several months in a few spreadsheets on Windows 10.

**Actions Taken:**

1. Select and Copy a cell in a spreadsheet.

   - Observed in Windows 10 / Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 Version 2007
   - Observed in Windows 10 / LibreOffice 6.2.8.2 (x64)
   - [Reported in Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/18551242), but I could not reproduce in Windows 10 / Chrome / Google Sheets
2. Copy a value in another
   application.
3. Paste in a cell in the spreadsheet.

**Behavior Observed:**

The value copied in step 1 is used. The value copied in step 2 seems to be unavailable. The step 2 copy stored in the system clipboard pastes to non-spreadsheet applications correctly.

**Expected Behavior:**

Paste actions fill the value from the most recent copy (system-wide).

**Desired Workaround:**

I don't think this is the place to argue the correctness of this new behavior, but is there a new keyboard command permutation to force pasting from the system clipboard? Or a flag in settings to modify this behavior? It's becoming disruptive, when working across applications.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this. I copied a cell in Excel, then copied some text from Firefox, then pasted in another cell. The text from Firefox was pasted. What application are you copying from that is not being recognized?

Comment: Hi @John,,, before U copy, just hit the Clipboard,, find on Home Tab,, in Copy & Paste section,,, now start copying one by one, you find data in Clipboard,, every version has limit,, now after you save & close the WB and open,, U find those copied data in Clipboard,, remain there till not deleted!

Comment: Could you provide the version number of Office you're using?